# Calcular media con una sola expressión con python

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe donde hay dos columnas que me dice el tipo de coche y las emisiones de CO2, necesito saber la media aritmetica de las emisiones de un solo tipo de coche, los familiares.
Hasta aquí hago lo siguiente y me sale la media correcta:

```
df_fam=df['Vehicle Class']=='FAMILY'
filter_df_fam = df[df_fam]
mean_CO2 = filter_df_fam.groupby(['Vehicle Class']).agg({'CO2 Emissions(g/km)': 'mean'})
print(mean_CO2)
```

Pero cómo seria utilizando una única expresión? Con algun tipo de bucle 'for' y condicional 'if'? No lo acabo de ver.

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Lo único que quieres es transformar esas 4 líneas a 1 sola?

Comment: Buenas tardes, sí exacto, que no se pueda hacer más de una asignación explícita de variables.